# HVAC -Can the fan run without the inducer's motor being on?

Tags: hvac

I have a HVAC system from around 2010.  The digital thermostat has various fan settings - HIGH, MED, LOW, AUTO.  The inducer motor seems to be OFF even though the fan is ON.  I notice cool air running through the vents when the thermostat is not asking for heat.  I read somewhere that the motor is always ON when the fan is ON.  Is that true?  Note, I have a variable-speed motor and it may be possible the motor is ON, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: The fan motor and the inducer motor are 2 separate motors. The fan can run without the inducer.

Comment: What setting do you have on for fan.  I think the auto setting is the one for when using heat, should turn on/off fan when heat is on.  The other settings mainly for warm months to run the fan without A/C.

Comment: @brhans is that true?  what i understand is like this: Inducer motors are composed of a fan, electrical box, and a small motor that powers a fan.  the fan that is running is part of the inducer motor assembly.  i did not know there was a separate fan motor.  Can someone else verify this?

Comment: @crip659 I have the fan set to HIGH.  I was testing to see if the inducer's motor started, but it does not; just the fan.

Comment: Most heating systems with a fan can have the fan(only) run with no heat, to just move air around.  When needing to heat, fan should be in auto mode, so the heater controls the fan.   The inducer/heater controls the fan, the fan does not control the inducer/heater.

Comment: The inducer is a little fan, and its purpose to create airflow for the furnace burners. The 'main' fan is a big fan, and its purpose is to move all the air through the HVAC system to heat (or cool) your house. 2 separate fans, and their airstreams typically should not mix, since you don't want the burners' combustion exhaust containing carbon monoxide, etc. to be mixed into your house's air. So the inducer will only run when your furnace is actively trying to heat the air, while the main fan could run any time you want the HVAC system to move air through your house.

Comment: @brhans they are part of the same assembly?  both fans? so the term 'blower' refers to the big fan i suppose?

Comment: @brhans nowhere on the internet can I find what you are saying to be the case

Comment: the one thing i did find is that the 'inducer motor' is also referred to as the 'burner fan'

Comment: I don't know what you're searching for - but literally the 1st result when I googled for "HVAC furnace diagram" was [this image](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/420312577695263206/) which shows the "Blower" aka the "big fan", and the "Inducer Motor" which drives the "little fan". And wouldn't you think that "the 'inducer motor' is also referred to as the 'burner fan'" corresponds pretty well with "The inducer is a little fan, and its purpose to create airflow for the furnace burners."?

Comment: @brhans actually no....IMHO 'little fan' does not associate well with inducer motor nor burner fan, especially when one doesn't understand furnaces well...

Comment: @brhans it still doesn't answer the question either, can the 'big fan' be running without the 'little fan'. the blower (big fan) needs power.  where does it get power from? electricity i suppose? capacitor?

Comment: i also don't know anything about motors, in this case, what they call AC induction motor, oh well :(

Answer (score 4):

If we are using these terms in the usual way, the *inducer* creates draft for combustion, through the combustion chamber and into the flue.  The *fan* circulates air through the house and through the heat exchanger.

The inducer should run whenever there is a call for heat, and possibly for a short time before and after if there is a logic control to do that.

The fan should run whenever there is a call for heat, or whenever the thermostat fan switch is set to Low, Medium, High, On, or randomly if the thermostat has such a setting, or for a short time after heating if there is logic in the system to do that.

If you have the thermostat fan setting on L/M/H/ON then yes you should feel cool air running when there is no call for heat.

If the inducer motor is running when there is no call for heat (or for a short time before or after) it may be wired incorrectly to be triggered by the fan and not the heat.

Comment: It depends on the system and How it is wired my last house had a 7 wire system. No matter what if I selected fan only that was the only thing running until a call for heat or cooling then the appropriate changes were made by the controller/ thermostat.

Comment: @jay613 yes, what you say makes sense, but the question remains.  Can the fan be running when the motor is off?

Comment: Two fans, two motors.  I've tried to clearly distinguish between fan and inducer, but your usage in the question and even here is ambiguous.  Which fan is running, how do you know it's running, which motor is off, how do you know it's off?